# Which IMEI number should I use to unlock my Motorola DROID 2 Global (A956): IMEI or IMEI SV?

Tags: motorola-droid, sim-unlocking, imei

I recently bought an unlock code to unlock a Motorola DROID 2 Global which was locked to the Verizon Wireless network.

Navigating to the *About phone* section: Menu -> Settings -> About Phone -> Status, I saw two IMEI numbers.

[image]

I used the top one (IMEI) as the code to complete the unlock process. However, when I tried to unlock the device, it rejected the code.

- Should I have used the IMEI SV?
- I have Android 2.3.4 but this device is normally equipped with 2.2, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use the IMEI.  The IMEI ends with a checksum, whereas IMEI SV ends with a Software Version number which shouldn't be relevant.